# Unit Fraction Addition

Tags: fractions

My teacher challenged us:

"Can you express the fraction $55\over 108$ as the sum of two unit fractions$?$"

I figured out that ${1\over 54} + {1\over 2} = {56\over 108}$ but I could not figure out a way to get $55\over 108$ as a sum of two unit fractions.

Any advice about how to approach this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

How about $\frac 12 + \frac 1{108}$?  Finding them in the general case can be difficult.  You can look up [Egyptian fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction#Calculation_methods) to find ways to express rationals as unit fractions, but often finding the shortest expansion is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{55}{108}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$, let $y≥x>0$, so $\frac{55}{108}>\frac{1}{x}⟹x>\frac{108}{55}$. The $x$ is integer, so $x≥2$, also rewrite the equation as form like $\frac{1}{108}=\frac{1}{55x}+\frac{1}{55y}$, and recalling $y≥x>0$, so that $55x≤108×2⟹x≤\frac{306}{55}$, hence $2≤x≤5$, this means that the possible values of $x$ are $x=2,3,4,5$，trying $x$
in such range one by one there is only one solution $\frac{55}{108}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{108}$.